# How to prevent loading of a page in the original frame?

Tags: html, hyperlink, frame

On my website I have a frame containing another page. When I click on a link (which is on the page in the frame) I get a new page in the same page. So, the whole web page is not reloaded (just content of the frame). Can I change this behavior? After the click I want to go to the new page (not just to have it in the original frame).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Target your link to _parent:

```
<a href="..." target="_parent">...</a>
```